# CSS prevent div from moving top

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

Here's the problem:

```
`http://jsfiddle.net/5gju85un/3/`
```

I want to prevend div #3 from moving higher while keep float left.
How can I do that?

**EDIT**

These divs are created by loop in my original code so I can't just make two parent divs.

**EDIT**

Inserted whole code (I'm making own template to use in wordpress)

**HTML/PHP**

```
if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post()?>
                        <div class="produkt ramka">
                            <div class="produkt_obraz">
                                <?php woocommerce_show_product_images();?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="produkt_nazwa">
                                <h3 class="produkt_litery"><?php woocommerce_template_single_title();?></h3>
                            </div>
                            <div class="produkt_cena">
                                <?php woocommerce_template_single_price();?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="produkt_line">
                            </div>
                            <div class="produkt_opis">
                                <?php the_content();?>
                            </div>
                            <div class="produkt_koszyk">
                                <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart()?>
                            </div>
                        </div>    

        <?php endwhile;
    }
```

**CSS**

```
.produkt
{
    display: inline-block;
    height:auto;
    min-height:120px;
    width:49.50%;
    margin-bottom:5px;
    background-color:#252525;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.produkt:nth-child(2n+1)
{
    float:left;
}
.produkt:nth-child(2n)
{
    float:right;
}
```

As you can see the code I've done in jsfiddle is based on this

Comment: are you trying to show the odd div no.s to the left & even ones to the right? like this http://jsfiddle.net/5gju85un/7/

Comment: Yes, but the height of 1st div is content dependent so I can't just make it straight x px.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5gju85un/4/)

```
<div class="divs st">div1</div>
<div class="divs nd">div2</div>
<div style="clear:both"></div>
<div class="divs rd">div3</div>
<div class="divs th">div4</div>
<div class="divs">div5</div>
<div class="divs">div6</div>
```

Comment: Oh... well nice but I want to move 4th div up to fill the space.

Comment: what you are looking for is masonry check this link then http://w3bits.com/css-masonry/

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that css masonry exists.